# Read elements from XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read from an XML file and use that to populate a question object I've created. This is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<quiz>
  <problem>
    <question>Which of the following languages could be used in both Visual Studio and Unity?</question>
    <answerA>Cobol</answerA>
    <answerB>C#</answerB>
    <answerC>C−−</answerC>
    <answerD>French</answerD>
    <correct>B</correct>
  </problem>
  <problem>
    <question>What does XML stand for?</question>
    <answerA>eXtremely Muddy Language</answerA>
    <answerB>Xerxes, the Magnificent Chameleon</answerB>
    <answerC>eXtensible Markup Language</answerC>
    <answerD>eXecutes with Multiple Limitations</answerD>
    <correct>C</correct>
  </problem>
</quiz>
```

This is the class I'm using. The problem is in the loadQuestions() method.

```
public partial class frmQuestions : Form
    {
        private XmlDocument doc;
        private XmlNode theQuiz;
        private List<Question> questions;
        private Random random;

        public frmQuestions(string docName)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(docName);
            questions = new List<Question>();          
            loadQuestions();
            displayQuestion();
        }

        private void frmQuestions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void loadQuestions()
        {
            string question, a, b, c, d, correct;
            theQuiz = doc.FirstChild;

            for(int i = 0; i < theQuiz.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                XmlNode theQuestion = theQuiz.ChildNodes[i];
                question = theQuestion["question"].InnerText;
                a = theQuestion["answerA"].InnerText;
                b = theQuestion["answerB"].InnerText;
                c = theQuestion["answerC"].InnerText;
                d = theQuestion["answerD"].InnerText;
                correct = theQuestion["correct"].InnerText;

                questions.Add(new Question(question, a, b, c, d, correct));
            }
        }

        private void displayQuestion()
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomNumber = random.Next(1, questions.Count);

            lblQuestion.Text = questions[randomNumber].getQuestion();
            lblA.Text = questions[randomNumber].getA();
            lblB.Text = questions[randomNumber].getB();
            lblC.Text = questions[randomNumber].getC();
            lblD.Text = questions[randomNumber].getD();
        }

    }
```

The problem I'm finding is that theQuiz.ChildNodes.Count = 0.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using LINQ to XML? It would make it considerably neater.

Comment: @Jon Lack of know-how. I'm relatively new to C# still.

Comment: @Habib.OSU I'll make an edit to show you

Comment: I have look at this **[How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)**. Refer to the **Wolf5** and **Tarkus** answer.

Comment: @Arcadian, just tried your code and changed one line, it seems to be working, check out my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code change `theQuiz = doc.FirstChild;` to

```
theQuiz = doc.LastChild;
```

The rest looks fine. (I couldn't find where you have defined theQuiz). I tried the code and it is working with `var theQuiz = doc.LastChild;`

If you want to use LINQ then you can try the following:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

            var query = (from x in xDoc.Descendants("quiz").Elements("problem")
                        select new Question
                        {
                            question = x.Element("question").Value,
                            answerA = x.Element("answerA").Value,
                            answerB = x.Element("answerB").Value,
                            answerC = x.Element("answerC").Value,
                            answerD = x.Element("answerD").Value,
                            correct = x.Element("correct").Value
                        }).ToList();
```

This is assuming that you have one class Question with properties exposed as question, answerA ... and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that seem's to do the job. Though I'm not sure why it works. Could you explain to me why lastchild works over firstchild?

Comment: @Arcadian, FirstChild was returning {XmlDeclaration, Value="version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\""}, whereas the LastChild was returning the Root node, you need to see this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C, Also adapt to LINQ its much easier and interesting

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ to XML:

Use LINQ to XML:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("YOURXML.xml");
var quiz = from elements in doc.Elements("quiz").Elements("problem")
           select elements;

foreach (var item in quiz)
{
question = item.Element("question").Value;
                    a = item.Element("answerA").Value; 
                    b = item.Element("answerB").Value; 
                    c = item.Element("answerC").Value; 
                    d = item.Element("answerD").Value; 
                    correct = item.Element("correct").Value; 
 questions.Add(new Question(question, a, b, c, d, correct));
}
```