# SSRS - Can I probe what reports have what fields like an information schema?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, report, information-schema

In the same was as one can query the information scehema in SQL Server to get a list of all tables and columns for a database, can one get a list of all the reports and the fields they reference in SSRS?

Is there something akin to an information schema on the reporting server?

I have a list of 800 reports for which I need to extract all fields, so I need this automated.

Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

PS  I am a novice SSRS user although I have done advanced VBA and MDX queries within SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

You can [read them as XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Structure is:

```
<Report>
    <DataSet>
        <DataSets>
            <Query>
                <Field Name="Name1">
                    <DataField>Name1</DataField>
                    ...
                </Field>
                <Field Name="Name">
                    ...
                </Field>
                ...
```