# How can I get text and attributes values in my XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

XML example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<brand name="brand1" num_brand="118" enabled="True">
  <price>
    <nodePattern>pattern</nodePattern>
    <attribute type="text" ></attribute>
    <treatment enabled="1" type="Regex">reg</treatment>
  </price>
  <title>
    <nodePattern>pattern</nodePattern>
    <attribute type="text" ></attribute>
    <treatment enabled="1" type="Regex">reg</treatment>
  </title>
</brand>
```

Please, how can I get the different attributes values and text for all my different nodes  (for example name, num_brand and enabled for brand, enabled, type and "reg" for treatment) using System.Xml.Linq ?

Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What are you struggling with?  How do you want to get these values (in a single string? loaded into a class?)

Comment: The question now is what is your problem? Depending on what you want, Linq to XML is quite easy. e.g. `var x = doc.Root.Attribute("num_brand").Value;` gives you the text of that attribute..

Answer (score 1):

The `System.Xml.Linq` namespace is much nicer than the `System.Xml` namespace. Your `XDocument` has one `XElement`, which in turn has children elements. Each element has attributes and a value.

Here's an example for you:

```
var text = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>
            <brand name=""brand1"" num_brand=""118"" enabled=""True"">
                <price>
                <nodePattern>pattern</nodePattern>
                <attribute type=""text"" ></attribute>
                <treatment enabled=""1"" type=""Regex"">reg</treatment>
                </price>
                <title>
                <nodePattern>pattern</nodePattern>
                <attribute type=""text"" ></attribute>
                <treatment enabled=""1"" type=""Regex"">reg</treatment>
                </title>
            </brand>";

XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(text);

// one root element - "brand"          
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(document.Elements().Count() == 1);
XElement brand = document.Element("brand");

// brand has two children - price and title           
foreach (var element in brand.Elements())
    Console.WriteLine("element name: " + element.Name);

// brand has three attributes
foreach (var attr in brand.Attributes())
    Console.WriteLine("attribute name: " + attr.Name + ", value: " + attr.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do that. One of them is the XmlDocument.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(myXML);
foreach(XmlNode node in xmlDoc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes){
    string text = node.InnerText; //you can loop through children
}
```

Take a look on this post :
[How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Personnaly I like the Linq To Xml approach, more infos here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx

Comment: Your answer suggests using `XmlDocument`, which is not using `System.Xml.Linq` (what the question is about).  It also is specifying how to get the `InnerText` rather than attribute values...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENMAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENMAME);

            var brand = doc.Descendants("brand").Select(x => new
            {
                name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
                num_brand = x.Attribute("num_brand").Value,
                enabled = x.Attribute("enabled").Value,
                nodePattern = x.Element("price").Element("nodePattern").Value,
                attribute = x.Element("price").Element("attribute").Attribute("type").Value,
                priceTreatmentEnable = x.Element("price").Element("treatment").Attribute("enabled").Value,
                priceTreatmentType = x.Element("price").Element("treatment").Attribute("type").Value,
                priceTreatment = x.Element("price").Element("treatment").Value,
                titleTreatmentEnable = x.Element("title").Element("treatment").Attribute("enabled").Value,
                titleTreatmentType = x.Element("title").Element("treatment").Attribute("type").Value,
                titleTreatment = x.Element("title").Element("treatment").Value
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
​
```