# Selecting the value of XML elements

Tags: c#, xmlreader

I don't have much experience with XML files but I'm trying to append a tutorial I found online to suite my needs and I'm not getting the results I would expect.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/307548/how-to-read-xml-from-a-file-by-using-visual-c

I've searched around but everything I've found doesn't make sense to me.

My XML looks like this for the most part:

```
<US>
    <!-- Kentucky Start -->
    <State>Kentucky KY
        <City>Newport
            <Street>Pavilion Parkway<Number>130<PostalCode>41071</PostalCode></Number></Street>
        </City>
        <City>Corbin
            <Street>Highway 90<Number>7351<PostalCode>40701</PostalCode></Number></Street>
        </City>
    </State>
</US>
```

I'm trying to populate a listbox with the value of each state but my code either returns white space or just the text within the XML tag

e.g. 
  State..
  State..
repeated for each element.

```
          while (reader.Read()) {
                switch (reader.NodeType) {

                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.

                        // Skip over root element
                        if (reader.Name.Equals("US")) {

                            reader.MoveToNextAttribute();

                        }
                        else {

                            if(reader.Name.Equals("State")) {
                                lbState.Items.Add(reader.Name);
                                lbState.Items.Add(reader.Value);
                            }

                        }
                        break;
```

reader.Name returns "State"
reader.Value returns "Whitespace"

I don't understand why reader.Value does not return Kentucky KY...
I've seen other examples that use string builder, is this a bad approach?

Comment: Is there any reason you really need to use `XmlReader`? It's a relatively low-level API which works well if you need to stream an *enormous* document, but it's normally much simpler to load the whole document into memory with LINQ to XML (`XDocument` etc)

Comment: I would try to avoid the `XmlReader` the API is not really friendly...

Comment: There is no particular reason. As I mentioned earlier, I have very little to almost no experience with XML or reading in XML files in. I was simply able to get the tutorial posted working in a console app and went with it. Do you have a recommendation? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Just stumbled on this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

I think this may be what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `reader.ReadString()` instead of `reader.Value`

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you. I'll probably use one of the other answers but technically this answered my question as it was asked.

Comment: I would suggest you to stick to XmlReader due to it's high performance with large Xml. (It's like a SAX parser, fast and forward only)

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq :

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            var results = doc.Descendants("State").Select(x => new {
                cities = x.Elements("City").Select(y => new {
                    state = (string)x,
                    city = (string)y,
                    streets = y.Elements("Street").Select(z => (string)z).ToList()
                }).ToList()
            }).SelectMany(x => x.cities).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would this be added to a listbox?

Comment: I'm mean printing results works but what do I use to print off the states and cities separately?

Comment: You can enumerate through results to get an value foreach(var result in results)

Answer (score 1):

You can use XmDocument (see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) and then use an xpath expression to get the right elements from your document:

Also it is better to encapsulate the name of the state (that is, if you own the xml document) like this:

```
<name>Kentucy KY</name>
```

So you can do the following:

```
var items = new List<string>();

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml("yourxml");
var xmlNodes = xmlDocument.SelectNodes("//State/Name");
foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNodes)
{
    items.Add(xmlNode.Value);
}
```