# I need to read xml file data but due to attribute it does not work

Tags: c#, xml, model-view-controller, attributes

i want to read xml file but due to Document node attribute it did not read file.

```
    Code C#: 
XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/MMS-CREATE-ALLA-ALLAH2H1-23102018-000170-INP.xml"));
            XmlNode settings = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Document[@xmlns='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01']/MndtInitnReq/GrpHdr");
            stu.BranchName = settings.SelectSingleNode("MsgId").InnerText;

XML FIle:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01">
    <MndtInitnReq>
        <GrpHdr>
            <MsgId>10005226074</MsgId>
            <CreDtTm>2018-10-23T15:20:56</CreDtTm>
    </GrpHdr>
</MndtInitnReq>
</Document>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a namespace that must be used to get the data.  Try Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication75
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string msgId = (string)doc.Descendants(ns + "MsgId").FirstOrDefault();
            XElement xCreDtTm =  doc.Descendants(ns + "CreDtTm").FirstOrDefault();

            //will give 1/1/01 when null
            DateTime CreDtTm = xCreDtTm == null ? new DateTime() : (DateTime)xCreDtTm;


        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Post a sample of the xml with multiple attributes.  Right now you have NO attribute in the xml, only elements.

Comment: <GrpHdr>
       <MsgId>10005226074</MsgId>
       <CreDtTm>2018-10-23T15:20:56</CreDtTm>
       <InstgAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
         <ClrSysMmbId>
          <MmbId>ARTD0211860</MmbId>
         </ClrSysMmbId>
         <Nm>ATEST BANK</Nm>
        </FinInstnId>
       </InstgAgt>
       <InstdAgt>
        <FinInstnId>
         <ClrSysMmbId>
          <MmbId>40123424</MmbId>
         </ClrSysMmbId>
         <Nm>test t CO-OP. BANK LTD</Nm>
        </FinInstnId>
       </InstdAgt>
      </GrpHdr>

Comment: what about if any node is not there how can i handle error for null node exception.
i am getting following error,
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Xml.Linq.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.

Comment: I updated code to handle null.  A DateTime can never be null according to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think loading this xml should be a problem. I verified that by loading the xml you posted in an XmlDocument object.
However I think, your xpath to get "settings" node should have xml namespace in all tags after Document.
So the xpath should be "**/*[local-name()='Document' and namespace-uri()='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01']/*[local-name()='MndtInitnReq' and namespace-uri()='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01']/*[local-name()='GrpHdr' and namespace-uri()='urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.009.001.01']**"