# search xml elements with if statement in C#

Tags: c#

I have different xml files and would like to get one specific value from each xml. 
what i'm trying to do is to search some of the elements in the xml and then when there is specific value or reference, then get the value of this reference.
for example one xml has this:

```
<textInfo>
 <freeText>
  <informationType>15</informationType>
 </freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
 <freeText>
  <textSubject>4</textSubject>
  <informationType>47</informationType>
 </freeText>
  <freeText>some text</freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
 <freeText>
  <informationType>733</informationType>
  <status>1</status>
 </freeText>
</textInfo>
```

other xml has more than that, for example:

```
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>15</informationType>
    <status>0</status>
  </freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>47</informationType>
  </freeText>
  <freeText>some text</freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <status>0</status>
  </freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>61</informationType>
  </freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>39</informationType>
  </freeText>
  <freeText>some text</freeText>
  <freeText>some other text</freeText>
</textInfo>
```

so what i tried to do is to first find the Length and how many  tags in the xml and then use Foreach or While and then IF statement where  tag equals 39 then get the value of the freeText tag

```
foreach (search all <textInfo>)
{
 if (<informationType> ==39)
   {
     do get the value of <freeText> of that <informationType>
   }
}
```

my problem is i don't know which to use in this case, should i use Foreach or while. and how to use it.

Note: i'm only getting the xml from webservice. i'm not storing it somewhere or have it as xml file. i'm just handling all the xml in my project and only stuck on this searching multiple tags to find one value

**EDIT/update** 
i have tried below two codes but both are returning a Null value

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(requestInterceptor.LastResponseXML);

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//textInfo/freeText[informationType>=39]/informationType"))
  {
   Object.Type = node.InnerText;
  }
```

other code:

```
XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(requestInterceptor.LastResponseXML);
var query = doc1.Descendants("textInfo").Where(ft => ((int?)ft.Element("informationType")).Equals("39"));
from c in doc1.Root.Descendants("textInfo")
where (c.Attribute("informationType").Equals("39"))
select c.Element("freeText");
Object.Type = query.ToString();
```

Comment: [Linq to XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-overview) can help you to query the content of the file in an easy way. But your structure is not fixed (freeText sometimes has a string or other fields) so I could become a mess to work with ...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

Comment: thank you @lordvlad30, but i'm only getting the xml from webservice. i'm not storing it somewhere or have it as xml file. i'm just handling all the xml in my project and only stuck on this searching multiple tags to find one value

Comment: @Ghaly_m you can use the Linq to XML without having the file, like Jon Skeet said in his comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ to XML makes this sort of query simple. I believe you're trying to find all `<freeText>` elements which have a direct `<informationType>` child element with a value of 39. Assuming every `<informationType>` element actually contains an integer, you could use:

```
XDocument doc = ...;
var freeTextsWithInfoType39 = doc
    .Descendants("freeText")
    .Where(ft => ((int?) ft.Element("informationType")) == 39);
```

You can then use that however you want - perhaps with another query to transform the results, or a `foreach` loop.

Comment: is there a way to use this without the LINQtoXML as i don't have the XML file stored with me, i'm only getting it from a webservice and reading it and trying to get the required values.

Comment: @Ghaly_m: I don't understand - if you've got the XML, it doesn't matter *where* you got it from, you can still load it into an `XDocument`. If you've got it as a string, just use `XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(text);` for example.

Comment: it is returning a Null... XDocument doc1 = XDocument.Parse(requestInterceptor.LastResponseXML);
                    var query = doc1.Descendants("textInfo").Where(ft => ((int?)ft.Element("informationType")).Equals("39"));
                    from c in doc1.Root.Descendants("textInfo")
                    where (c.Attribute("informationType").Equals("39"))
                    select c.Element("freeText");

Comment: @Ghaly_m: That's not what the query was in my answer though. I looked for `freeText` elements which have a child `informationType` element with a value of 39, and I also didn't compare an *integer* with a *string*. The query that's actually in my answer finds a single `freeText` element. To get the `informationType` element, just ask for the parent.

Comment: my mistake, i edit it based on the answer, the exact code of yours returns System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Xml.Linq.XElement]

Comment: @Ghaly_m: Well yes, that's a sequence of `freeText` elements. So then do whatever you want with those elements, e.g. via a foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using XDocument, you can also use XmlDocument and XPath.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
 doc.Load(@"sample.xml");

 foreach(XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//textInfo/freeText[informationType>=39]/informationType"))
 {
      Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
 }
 //the print out should be:
 //47
 //61
 //39
```

For more infomation about XPath, please refer to:https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

The sample xml string doesn't have a root element, if you want to load such xml string, you should format the xml string first.

```
var xml = @"<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>15</informationType>
    <status>0</status>
  </freeText>
</textInfo>
<textInfo>
  <freeText>
    <textSubject>4</textSubject>
    <informationType>47</informationType>
  </freeText>
  <freeText>some text</freeText>
</textInfo>"
var validXml = $"<resp>{xml}</resp>";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(validXml);
//The other code is the same as before.
```

Comment: i have tried the following but it is returning a Null .....   XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(requestInterceptor.LastResponseXML);

foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("//textInfo/freeText[informationType>=39]/informationType"))
     {
        EMD_Object.infoType = node.InnerText;
     }

Comment: @mylahg hi, mylahg, I just update my answer, I think you can refer to the latest answer.