# Custom Configuration Class with KeyValue pairs inside

Tags: c#, configuration

I want to implement the following configuration section:

```
<Services>
  <Service name="Service-1" provider="Provider-1" type="Type-1">
    <add key="Region" value="region-name-1"/>
    <add key="AccessKey" value="1234567890"/>
    <add key="SecretKey" value="asdfghhkl"/>
  </Service>
  <Service name="Service-2" provider="Provider-1" type="Type-2">
    <add key="Region" value="region-name-2"/>
    <add key="EndpointName" value="tyudfv.endpoint.com"/>
    <add key="AccessKey" value="1234567890"/>
    <add key="SecretKey" value="asdfghhkl"/>
  </Service>
</Services>
```

And I'm struggling with two issues:
   1. Retrieve list of  nodes without wrapping  with some parent ConfigurationSection
   2. Retrieve KeyValue collection of  node
Is there some obvious way here? Or it's just such complicated as I think?

Comment: what xml parser are you even using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Comment: Also take a look at this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815786/how-to-store-and-retrieve-custom-information-from-an-application-confi

Comment: I want to ready this section from web.config with custom class, as I wrote. So I appreciate if someone can explain me how to do this. And If it's even possible without any complications (like read XML directly or something like this)