# how to get value(node) value from XML using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, xml

```
<AspResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" status="1" transId="6c8c5901-6119-4c59-89ce-b3f9efb141f2">
    <EResp errCode="NA" errMsg="NA" resCode="ea3229b1-c9ff-455b-8d3f-84a4c2384c85" status="1" ts="2020-04-27T15:00:10.947" txn="90f4f36f-7051-4c6d-bed4-bd717ddfa38d">
        <Signatures>
            <DocSignature error="NA" id="1">test</DocSignature>
        </Signatures>
    </EResp>
</AspResp>
```

I want value of `transId` from first node in the above XML.

I used this code but it is useless

```
foreach (XElement hashElement in doc.Descendants("transId"))
{
    hashValue = (string)hashElement;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select required node. Since `transId` is an attribute, you should access like this:

```
string attrtransId  = node.Attributes["transId"].value
```

Comment: I think this needs a bit more detail to be useful, it doesn't relate to the code in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this, It's very detailed & easy to understand.

[How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

```
string XMLText = @"<AspResp errCode='NA' errMsg='NA' status='1' transId='6c8c5901-6119-4c59-89ce-b3f9efb141f2'><EResp errCode='NA' errMsg='NA' resCode='ea3229b1-c9ff-455b-8d3f-84a4c2384c85' status='1' ts='2020-04-27T15:00:10.947' txn='90f4f36f-7051-4c6d-bed4-bd717ddfa38d'><Signatures><DocSignature error='NA' id='1'>test</DocSignature></Signatures></EResp></AspResp>";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(XMLText);
        XmlNode node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("AspResp")[0];
        string transId = node.Attributes["transId"].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested xpath with http://xpather.com/2S8920tn

```
string XMLText =
            @"<AspResp errCode='NA' errMsg='NA' status='1' transId='6c8c5901-6119-4c59-89ce-b3f9efb141f2'><EResp errCode='NA' errMsg='NA' resCode='ea3229b1-c9ff-455b-8d3f-84a4c2384c85' status='1' ts='2020-04-27T15:00:10.947' txn='90f4f36f-7051-4c6d-bed4-bd717ddfa38d'><Signatures><DocSignature error='NA' id='1'>test</DocSignature></Signatures></EResp></AspResp>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(XMLText);
string transId = doc.XPathSelectElement("/node()[1]").Attribute("transId")?.Value;
```