# How to receive XML in c# and variable

Tags: c#, xml, web-applications

I know this is a silly question but I am receiving to my endpoint xml, upon receiving it I would like to extract a value from the xml and display it as a response. I am using the .Net Framework Web API project in Visual studio

Here is the xml someone is sending to my API endpoint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Message>
<ResultCode>3</ResultCode>
</Message>
```

The other challenge I have related to this question is how do I receive the XML above? Usually an xml file would be called via "doc.Load("c:\temp.xml");" but how do I receive the XML inside my API and from there extract the ResultCode value.
This is the header of my API code:

```
public string Post(string incomingXML)
{

}
```

Comment: maybe you're looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

Comment: Thanks that helped already... The other challenge I have related to this question is how do I receive the XML above?


In this link, they use "doc.Load("c:\\temp.xml");" as the file which contains the XML. How do I substitute that with the incoming POST on my API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the 1st question, you don't need a file, you can use

```
doc.LoadXml(@"<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>
<Message>
<ResultCode>3</ResultCode>
</Message>");
```

or

`doc.LoadXml(incomingXML)` for your case

About your 2nd question if it still actual. There is not enough information, but there is all options for you:

- [the best solution] you can use `Server.MapPath("~/path/your.xml")` (or `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/path/your.xml")`) - `~` here means root folder of your webapp. You need to have that xml in folder with webapp created manualy, or uploaded in future.
- you can change `Copy to Output Directory` option to the 2nd or the 3rd, so it could be possible to access your file with `doc.Load("your.xml")`. You need to have that xml in folder with webapp in time of build.

[image: Copy to Output Directory]

- [not required solution] you could let your IIS process to access other folders then your webapp is - right click on folder with your xml -> Properties -> Security -> Edit -> Add

[image: iis_iusrs]

Then write `IIS_IUSRS` at text area, click Check Names and Ok. Now you can specify Access

[image]

In future please create one question for one problem.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The main issue is not the XML file but how to load an incoming API call that has a XML body and then to use that in code. The "string incomingXML" in my code header is expecting a URL POST that is for example HTTP://A.A.com?incomingXML=.... however this XML is coming in the body and hence I need to extract it from body and then get the "ResposeCode" element

Comment: I don't know how do you pass that to API, but here 2 options: add attribute to parameter `[FromBody]string incomingXML`. or, if body is json object, you have to create new `public class MyResponseModel{ public string incomingXML}` and you post become `Post([FromBody]MyResponseModel model)`. There are also option with `StreamReader`: `using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, ncoding.UTF8)) var textFromBody = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();` and your post will be with out parameters `string Post()`

Comment: Thank you, if I add to my Post the '[FromBody] string incomingXML' how would I get the ResultCode value as a variable?

Comment: I don't get your question. It should be in your `incomingXML` variable, and you will use `doc.LoadXml(incomingXML)`. It will work is your body string, but usualy it is json object so if incomingXML is null, then use 2nd method from my comment (with new class).

Comment: Apologies for being unclear :-). Let me ask it this way. In the XML example above there is <ResultCode>3</ResultCode> inside the object <Message>. After I have added doc.LoadXml(incomingXML) how do I get the value of <ResultCode>?

Comment: `doc.Descendants("ResultCode").FirstOrDefault();`