# How to speed up a Regex with Atomic groups?

Tags: c#, regex, powershell

The regular expression (.NET/C# flavor, or PS flavor) listed below matches elements and inner text in a simple XML file line by line (multiline matches are not necessary).

```
^[^<]*<(?'Element'[^>\s]*)[^>]*>(?'Text'[^<]*)<\/\1>\s*$
```

This regex matches the following inputs correctly and quite efficiently:
See the [**online simulation**](https://regex101.com/r/mw7zKn/1).

```
    <ELEMENT>inner text</ELEMENT>
       <ELEMENT>inner text</ELEMENT>
       <ELEMENT>inner text</ELEMENT>   
    <ELEMENT >   inner text   </ELEMENT>
    <ELEMENT >   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
       <ELEMENT >   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
    <ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
       <ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>
```

However cases which are not supposed to match, perform correctly but they incur a lot of backtracking and thus are very inefficient:
See the [**online simulation**](https://regex101.com/r/mw7zKn/1).

```
      ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
    < ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
       < ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>   
    <ELEMENT>inner text</FOO>
    ELEMENT ATTRIB="foo">   inner text   </ELEMENT>
```

**QUESTION**: Can I use atomic groups to prevent this backtracking and speed up the mismatching performance without slowing down the matching performance ...and how?

If .Net & PS supported possessive quantifiers, I would be asking about them, too.

P.S.
*This question is applicable **not only** to XML inputs.  It is about general regex optimization with atomic groups in .NET or PS - not about processing this particular XML input.*

Comment: Suggestion: use an XML parser mate! You will be much better with it.

Comment: Take a look here, I don't think that post has nearly enough good examples or ways of doing it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use atomic groups to prevent this backtracking and speed up the mismatching performance without slowing down the matching performance

No. Every time one uses `*` (zero or more) in a pattern, it by its definition will use backtracking to find **every** possible occurrence that could happen.

Your pattern is so *backtracking friendly* that providing an answer to this question which does everything you want would be foolhardy.

Regex is a pattern matching tool and not a lexical analysis tool. I believe you are confusing the two in this situation.

As mentioned in the comments use a tool more suited to either HTML or XML to parse and analyze your data.