# Get Value From XML Object

Tags: c#, xml

I am struggling to find out how to pull out the tracking number(s) values from the following XML:

```
 <ShipmentHeader>
    <DocumentID>62017836-1</DocumentID>
    <DocumentReference type="CustomerSuppliedReference">
       <DocumentID>
          <ID>10532</ID>
       </DocumentID>
    </DocumentReference>
    <Status>
       <Code/>
       <Description languageID="en-us"/>
    </Status>
    <ActualShipDateTime>2023-06-07T09:16:33-04:00</ActualShipDateTime>
    <ShippingMethod>CHEAPEST METHOD W/FIRST CLASS</ShippingMethod>
    <DocumentReference type="TrackingNumber">
       <TrackingNumber>9200190233107605458375</TrackingNumber>
    </DocumentReference>
 </ShipmentHeader>
```

From what I have seen, it seems that I must use reflection, but I just cannot get it to work.
Can anyone give me any pointers please?

Comment: "From what i have seen it seem i must used reflection" - no, definitely not. I suggest you read a tutorial on LINQ to XML, which is a really powerful and easy-to-use XML API.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I read and parse an XML file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642293/how-do-i-read-and-parse-an-xml-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
    var results = XDocument.Parse(xml)
       .Descendants("TrackingNumber")
       .Select(e => e.Value)
       .FirstOrDefault(); // Or .ToList() maybe
```

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more performant method than @Serge, still using `XDocument`

```cs
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

var result = 
    doc.Root
       .Elements("DocumentReference")
       .Where(e => (string)e.Attribute("type") == "TrackingNumber")
       .SelectMany(e => e.Elements("TrackingNumber"))
       .Select(e => e.Value);
```

---

Or you can use XQuery

```cs
var result = doc.XPathSelectElements(
    @"/ShipmentHeader/DocumentReference[@type=""TrackingNumber""]/TrackingNumber")
  .Select(e => e.Value);
```

[**dotnetfiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/agDhJ6)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to find any "TrackingNumber" element, at any level:

```
void Main()
{
    string s = @"<ShipmentHeader>
            <DocumentID>62017836-1</DocumentID>
            <DocumentReference type=""CustomerSuppliedReference"">
               <DocumentID>
                  <ID>10532</ID>
               </DocumentID>
            </DocumentReference>
            <Status>
               <Code/>
               <Description languageID=""en-us""/>
            </Status>
            <ActualShipDateTime>2023-06-07T09:16:33-04:00</ActualShipDateTime>
            <ShippingMethod>CHEAPEST METHOD W/FIRST CLASS</ShippingMethod>
            <DocumentReference type=""TrackingNumber"">
               <TrackingNumber>9200190233107605458375</TrackingNumber>
            </DocumentReference>
         </ShipmentHeader>";
         
    var numbers = XElement.Parse(s)
        .Descendants("TrackingNumber")
        .Select(xe => (string)xe);
        
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an alternative way;

```
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml("your xml");

    XmlNodeList trackingNumberNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//DocumentReference[@type='TrackingNumber']/TrackingNumber");
    foreach (XmlNode node in trackingNumberNodes)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/N5eNno